# Cannot spell check words of less than seven characters with UITextChecker

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm attempting to check whether a word is in the dictionary with the following function

```swift
func isReal(word: String) -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
    let wordRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
    return wordRange.location == NSNotFound
}
```

The problem is that this only works correctly for words of seven characters or more. Shorter words return true even if they are not in the dictionary. Specifically, we get `wordRange = {9223372036854775807, 0}` in this case, the same as for a valid word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turns out to be embarrassingly simple. Our strings were upper case, and `UITextChecker` treats any upper case string shorter than seven characters as a possible valid acronym. In lower case everything works as expected.

Comment: Simple is good! Thanks for figuring this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I find it works just fine, when I use your function in a Swift Playground:

```
import UIKit

func isReal(word: String) -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
    let wordRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
    return wordRange.location == NSNotFound
}

let validStrings = ["test", "fest", "fast"]
let validResults = validStrings.map{ isReal(word:$0) }
print(validResults)

let invalidStrings = ["xt", "fxxx", "srwe"]
let invalidResults = invalidStrings.map{ isReal(word:$0) }
print(invalidResults)
```

Your issue may be platform or version specific.